# Procedural Function not evaluating

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation

I have this function (Nhfunction) defined as procedural:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ClearAll[Subscript]
(*Set of static parameters*)
rho = 2; r = 0.8;
m = 3; n = 2 ;
A = Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, n}];
Subscript[a, 1] = 0.5;
Subscript[a, 2] = 1 - Subscript[a, 1];    
V = Table[Subscript[v, i], {i, m}];
Subscript[v, 1] = 0.2;
Subscript[v, 2] = 0.4;
Subscript[v, 3] = 0.6;
G = Table[Subscript[g, i], {i, m}];
Subscript[g, 1] = 0.3;
Subscript[g, 2] = 0.4;
Subscript[g, 3] = 0.3;

(*Definition of the function that fails to evaluate*)
Nhfunction[c1_, c2_] :=
  Module[{},
   (*Function that take the arguments c1 of Nhfunction as parameter*)
   W1[i_, j_] := 
    rho*Subscript[a, 1]/
      r*(Subscript[v, i] - 
       rho/r*(Sum[
           Subscript[g, z]*
            Subscript[a, 1]*(Subscript[v, z] - Subscript[v, i]), {z, 
            i + 1, j}] + 
          Sum[Subscript[g, 
             k]*(Subscript[v, 
               k] - (Subscript[a, 1]*Subscript[v, i] + 
                Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[v, j])), {k, j + 1, m}]) - 
       c1)*(1 - Sum[Subscript[g, s], {s, 1, i - 1}]);

   (*Similar function that takes c2*)
   W2[i_, j_] := 
    rho*Subscript[a, 2]/
      r*(Subscript[v, i] - 
       rho/r*(Sum[
           Subscript[g, z]*
            Subscript[a, 2]*(Subscript[v, z] - Subscript[v, i]), {z, 
            i + 1, j}] + 
          Sum[Subscript[g, 
             k]*(Subscript[v, 
               k] - (Subscript[a, 2]*Subscript[v, i] + 
                Subscript[a, 1]*Subscript[v, j])), {k, j + 1, m}]) - 
       c2)*(1 - Sum[Subscript[g, s], {s, 1, i - 1}]);

(*Table of preliminar results*)
   game = Table[Subscript[p, i, j, z], {i, m}, {j, m}, {z, n}];
   Do[Subscript[p, i, j, 1] = W1[i, j]; 
    Subscript[p, i, j, 2] = W2[j, i], {i, m}, {j, m}];

   (*Nash Table *)
   nash = Table[Subscript[nh, i, j], {i, m}, {j, n}];
   Do[Subscript[nh, i, 
      1] = {Position [game[[All, i, 1]], Max[game[[All, i, 1]]]], i} //
       Flatten, {i, m}];
   Do[Subscript[nh, i, 
      2] = {i, Position [game[[i, All, 2]], Max[game[[i, All, 2]]]]} //
       Flatten, {i, m}];
   Nasheq = Select[nash[[All, 1]], MemberQ[nash[[All, 2]], #] &];

(*Function expected output *)
      Return[Nasheq[[1, All]]]];
```

Some tested results:

```
Nhfunction[0,0]={2,2}
Nhfunction[1,1]={3,3}
Nhfunction[0,1]={2,3}
```

The issue is that if I run that code and then evaluate Nhfunction I get the proper result, but if then I evaluate new arguments on Nhfunction, the result doesn't change. However if I insist on the new arguments the output change to the correct one after 3 tries. For example:

1st evaluation:
`Nhfunction[0,0]={2,2}` correct output.

Change arguments:

`Nhfunction[1,1]={2,2}` incorrect output.

(2nd) Enter on the line `Nhfunction[1,1]={2,2}` incorrect output.

(3rd) Enter on the line `Nhfunction[1,1]={3,3}` correct output.

I noted that the tables game and nash are not updating properly, but they update (with delay). This is what I tried without luck:

- Define the game and nash table as module.
- use p/: and nh/: to assign values to the tables and then ClearAll[game] and ClearAll[nash]
- Evaluate[] on the Do that fills the tables (get an error on the nash table)

I need to eventually plot `Nhfunction[x,y]`

Comment: The very first thing that comes to my mind is: Don't use `Subscript`. Better use lists/arrays and `Part` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `Subscript` was very puzzling (and inefficient) This is the way I would write your algorithm down. I did not experience any delaying issues with this implementation. But of course, no guarantee that it does what you have in mind.

```
rho = 2;
r = 0.8;
R = rho/r;
m = 3;
n = 2;
a = {0.5, 1 - 0.5};
v = {0.2, 0.4, 0.6};
g = {0.3, 0.4, 0.3};

W1[c1_, i_, j_] := 
  R a[[1]] (v[[i]] - 
     R ( a[[1]] Sum[g[[z]] (v[[z]] - v[[i]]), {z, i + 1, j}] + 
        Sum[g[[k]] (v[[k]] - (a[[1]] v[[i]] + a[[2]] v[[j]])), {k, 
          j + 1, m}]) - c1) (1 - Sum[g[[s]], {s, 1, i - 1}]);
W2[c2_, i_, j_] :=
  R a[[2]] (v[[j]] - 
     R (a[[2]] Sum[g[[z]] (v[[z]] - v[[j]]), {z, j + 1, i}] + 
        Sum[g[[k]] (v[[k]] - (a[[2]] v[[j]] + a[[1]] v[[i]])), {k, 
          i + 1, m}]) - c2) (1 - Sum[g[[s]], {s, 1, j - 1}]);

Nhfunction[c1_, c2_] := First@Intersection[
    Table[{Ordering[Table[W1[c1, i, j], {i, m}], -1][[-1]], j}, {j, m}],
    Table[{i, Ordering[Table[W2[c1, i, j], {j, m}], -1][[-1]]}, {i, m}]
    ];
```

Here some test results:

```
Nhfunction[0, 0]
Nhfunction[1, 1]
Nhfunction[0, 1]
```

> {2, 2}
>
> {3, 3}
>
> {2, 3}

Comment: Thanks, I would try to implement something like your solution without subscripts. I can't really use your code directly.

Comment: You're welcome. My principal goal was to show that operating with arrays and `Table` might help to write more concise code that is also easier to debug.

Comment: Worked perfectly once I avoided the subscripts, thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome.